# Tail bound regime for Binomial distribution in concentration paper

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, measure-concentration, binomial-distribution

In paper '[Concentration Inequalities and Martingale Inequalities:A Survey](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/concen.pdf)' gives the following inequality:

[image: uhun]

My question is whether the inequality holds in regime $\lambda$ being $o(\sqrt n)$ (say $\lambda$ as small as $n^{1/5}$)?

No particular regime appears in the paper however I wanted to confirm.

If not what regime does it hold?

I am interested in Binomial distribution.

Comment: Linyuan Lu is also an author of the paper.

Comment: Thank you..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower tail bound holds for all $\lambda\in[0,EX]$ and hence for all real $\lambda\ge0$; see the [more general bounds in (1.3)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06482).

The upper tail bound, too, holds for all real $\lambda\ge0$; it follows immediately from [Bernstein's inequality, Section 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)#Some_of_the_inequalities).

Comment: at lambda = 1 the sum of tail probabilities is 2. Can I use multiplicative 0.5 constant before the mentioned fornulss or subtract 0.5?

Comment: @VS. : No, you cannot do that. However, you can use $\min(1,\text{"the sum of tail probabilities"})$ instead of "the sum of tail probabilities".